# After ubuntu update, mouse scrolls to right on its own when hovering

Tags: updates, mouse

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS and just finished updating. However a new problem cropped up after update. When I hover my mouse pointer over anything, it just scrolls to right automatically. That practically makes everything with a horizontal span unworkable as as soon as I hover mouse it just keeps scrolling right.

Any solutions?

Comment: I just realised its an issue with bluetooth mouse which was working before update. Now a wired mouse works perfectly.